# Java list all used imports of project per file

Tags: java, import

How can I list all used imports per file of a whole java project?

Part of the requirements is to ignore unused imports but have all the used items imported via wildcard listed seperately.

Comment: IDEs can list all unused imports. Can you use this information to list all used imports?

Comment: Not with wildcard imports, right?

Comment: At least in NetBeans, if no classes are used from a wildcard import, it'll be flagged as unused. Could you please somehow explain this: "Part of the requirements is to ignore unused imports but have all the used items imported via wildcard listed seperately."? I can't figure out what you are after.

Comment: I want a list of all the used ones, also from wildcard imports

Comment: One way is to first [refactor all wildcard imports to explicit ones](https://superuser.com/questions/1357673/java-refactor-implicit-wildcard-imports-to-explicit-imports) and then grep the file or whole project. (I posted it as an answer but it had been converted to a comment )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Step 1: Replace all wildcard imports with explicit ones

### 1.a) Get IntelliJ IDEA

If you don't have it yet, get JetBrain's IntelliJ IDEA in your preferred way (package manager, [official download](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/), [JetBrains' Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/), ...)
The community edition should probably be enough.

### 1.b) Choose Import code style to not use wildcard imports

Annotated screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YParH.jpg

- Open the Settings (`File > Settings` or `Ctrl+Alt+S`)
- Go to `Editor > Code Style > Java` in the Settings Editor's navigation tree pane and open the `Imports` tab.
- In the `General` section (the first one) set [`Class count to use import with '*'`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.2/code-style-java.html?utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2018.2#d226430e811) and [`Names count to use static import with '*'`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.2/code-style-java.html?utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2018.2#d226430e816) to high levels, like `99`

### 1.c) Optimize Imports

- Select the file or folder you want to examine.
  *(Make sure not to select other files and folders, as organizing the imports for a lot of files may take quite a while and the optimization is being done **on disk** and not in memory / file buffers.)*
- Run [`Optimize Imports`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/optimizing-imports.html) (`Code > Organize Imports` or `Ctrl+Alt+O`)

## Step 2: Grep your file(s) for imports

IntelliJ IDEA automatically saves the import optimizations to disk, so you now only have all the used imports and have all of them as explicit ones, so you can just

- Grep the files or folders you want to examine for `import`

## (Optional Step 3: Revert your files to previous state)